# Vue - Unable to receive props data on child component after fetching data

Tags: vue.js, fetch

Im trying to pass the data gotten from fetching a JSON, to a child component to create v-cards. After a few hours, I can't find the problem. The only thing I notice is that the prop in the parent never gets the data after the fetching is finished.

```
App.vue (parent)

<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-tabs centered="centered">
      <v-tab v-for="tab in cities" :key="tab.id" @click='loadPacks(tab.id)'>{{tab.name}}</v-tab>
   </v-tabs>
  <cards v-if="chequeoData" :dataPaquetes="dataPackages" :key="dataPackages"/>
  </v-app> 
</template>

<script>
import cards from './components/Card.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    cards,
  },
  data: () => ({
    pepito: 0,
    rating: 3,
    centered: true,
    isFetching: false,
    chequeoData: false,
    cities: [{
      id: "pE",
      name: "Punta del Este"
    },{
      id: "cU",
      name: "Costa Uruguaya"
    }],
    dataPackages: [],
  }),
  methods: {
  loadPacks: function (val) {
      self.dataPackages = [];
      var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
      targetUrl = val == 'cU' ? '*****' : '*******';
      fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(data => {
          self.dataPackages = data.promociones;
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(self.dataPackages);
          self.chequeoData = true;
        })
    }
  },
  props: {
    dataPaquetes: self.dataPackages
  },
 mounted() {
    this.loadPacks()
  }
};
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons');


</style>
```

The console log shows the data with no problems, however the VUE dev tools show me that dataPaquetes is undefined[image]

```
Card.vue (Child component)

<template>
<v-container>
<v-layout>
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md3 lg3 v-for="item in dataPackages" :key="item.codigo">
<v-card>{{item.ciudad}}
</v-card>
</v-flex>
</v-layout>
</v-container>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'cards',
  props: ['dataPaquetes'],
  data: () => ({
      rating: 3,
      dataPackages: self.dataPaquetes,
    }),
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    self.dataPackages = self.dataPaquetes;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(self.dataPaquetes)
},
};
</script>
```

Thanks for reading, and for the help

Comment: What is `self` in you examples? Is that supposed to be `this`?

Comment: Yes, I usually use self instead of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is you not defined the data type of the props. you can try like this:

in child file:

```
props: {dataPaquetes: Object}, // depends on your data type

data: () => ({
      rating: 3,
      dataPackages: this.dataPaquetes,
    }),
```

in parent file you must declare `data.Paquetes` in data option instead of props. you cannot change props data. you only can change `data()` option

change to `this` instead of `self`

`this` is an actual JavaScript keyword that refers to the current scope, while `self` is a traditional variable name not a JavaScript keyword, often used to store the previous “this” scope before entering a new one.

and also one more thing, if `dataPackage` is just used to display in HTML, there is no need to re declare in `data()` just use the `{{dataPaquetes}}` in HTML. but if you are going to change the value, you can redeclare into the data.

Comment: I started to read guides about fetching data in Vue, and a few thing from there plus what you recommended made the trick.

1) Added the data type in the props
2) Called the API function in created instead of mounted
3) Changed all the selfs for this
4) Declared dataPackages in data as ' ', then at the start of the function declared var vm = this, and after retrieving the data redefined dataPackages with vm.dataPackages.

I don't know exactly which one of those made the trick but doing all the four, now it works. Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: most welcome. good to know it's help. i can see the real problem is where you define the data in props in parent file. that's why it'll not changing anything because we cannot alter the props data.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `this` instead of `self`. There is nothing to gain by breaking convention and forming bad habits.

In Vue, you can not declare the same variable in both `props` and in `data`. They are accessed the same way and will conflict with each other. Additionally, if you are fetching data asynchronously in your parent, make sure the data is updating and passing the prop down via binding properly.